# Action of torus on itself

Tags: group-theory, geometry, algebraic-geometry

I read somewhere that one considers the "natural action" of the $k$-points $T(k)$ ($k$ an algebraically closed field) of a torus $T$ defined over $k$, on $T$. What does one mean with "$T(k)$ naturally acting on $T$ ?''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T(k)$ is isomorphic as a group to $(k^*)^n$ where $n$ is the dimension of the torus.

Now your torus is the spectrum of $k[x_1,x_1^{-1},\ldots,x_n,x_n^{-1}]$, so $(k^*)^n$ acts on this ring by multiplying the $n$-th variable with the $n$-th entry.

e.g. $k^*$ acts on $k[x,x^{-1}]$ by $u\cdot x=u^{-1}x$. (I think one can do without the ${-1}$ on $u$.)

This is just to algebraically mimic the multiplication of torus.

Comment: Does this imply that $T(k)$ then acts on itself (induced action), as (say in the case $n = 2$)  $(u_1,u_2)\cdot(x,y) = (u_1x,u_2y)$, with $(x,y)$ any $k$-point ?

Comment: Yes. That is just the multiplication on the torus.